# The Meaning of 'Undecidable' in Metaphysics

Tags: metaphysics

It is often said that metaphysical questions are undecidable but not so often explained what this word means in a metaphysical context.

I'm wondering whether a mathematician would class metaphysical questions as undecidable, or whether philosophers are rather sloppy in the use of this word.

1. Where philosophers use the word 'undecidable' for metaphysical antinomies but do not define its meaning what would you naturally assume they mean?
2. Where they do define it, how do they usually do so?

I have my own views on this but I'm wondering if I'm misjudging the way people read this word in philosophy. If so, my own use of it may need to change.

Comment: No, they aren't using it in the way mathematicians use that word. But that doesn't mean philosophers are necessarily being sloppy. Mathematics has its own kind of language-game, and no one except mathematicians use the words mathematicians use in the same way. It's not as though mathematicians have some kind of final say on what words mean. For example, many recipes for pastries direct the chef to arrange the pastry material into a lattice. Mathematicians use 'lattice' in a rigorously defined way. Has the recipe writer been sloppy? No, they've conveyed precisely what they meant to convey.

Comment: It would help to see a specific context where "undecidable" is used. The uses I can think of refer to roughly the same thing as metaphysical claims being untestable, unverifiable and unfalsifiable, unanswerable in principle, etc. In mathematics decidability is relativized to a formal system and does not concern reality, here it is meant in a more absolute and real sense.

Comment: See [Carnap and metaphysics](https://www.iep.utm.edu/carnap/) : the critique on metaphysics is that (most of) its problems are *meaningless*; thus they cannot have a "solution": they are "fake" questions without answer. This is not the same sense of "undecidable" used in mathematics and logic. Undecidable statements/problems in modern logic are perfectly meaningful question in the language of the relevant theory.

Comment: @Conifold - Any of Kant's antinomies or Russell's 'problems' would do as an example. If your answer is that philosophers may often equate 'undecidable' with 'untestable, unverifiable and unfalsifiable' then they must get in a hell of a muddle. Are not most philosophers more careful than this? You may be right,and they are not, in which case your comment/answer is helpful and quite surprising to me.    .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Thanks. I get that some people think that such questions are meaningless, but I'm asking about those like Kant who think they are undecidable.

Comment: Kant's antinomies would not be an example. Kant does not say that the antinomies are irresolvable, he claims to resolve them by distinguishing things in themselves from appearances. The "metaphysical" questions then come out not as undecidable but meaningless, an artifact of the misuse of concepts. Even if we disagree with his solution, the antinomies are paradoxes, not undecidable questions, it is inconsistency, not incompleteness. I am not sure what you have in mind with Russell, his paradox is not about metaphysics but semantics, and again, a paradox.

Comment: @Conifold - We cannot argue here but I'm quite sure you're completely wrong about this. I share the view of Korner in his well-known study of Kant. If his antinomies are seen as paradoxes (which is not my view) it is because the two extreme views don't work. rendering them undecidable (by a certain definition), just as he claims. Also, while Russell failed to acknowledge the connection between his paradox and metaphysics this does not mean there is not one. Others considered him foolish for missing it.

Comment: Körner's book was a condensed introduction to Kant for laymen, not a serious exegesis. But, although its attribution to Kant is highly dubious, you are free to adopt Körner's view. This is why it helps to give specific context where the term is used, Körner is unlikely to come to mind from reading your post.

Comment: @Conifold -  Is it not the case that Kant undertook the critique of reason in order to resolve the scandal of ostensible contradictions of reason? What are these contradictions? They are questions (albeit they may be badly formed) for which the extreme answers cannot be endorsed, rendering such questions undecidable. There doesn't seem to  be anything ambiguous here. Korner's view is likely to be orthodox if he writes for students, and Kant makes it all quite clear in the Critique. I'm surprised to have to disagree about this.

Comment: Körner wrote in 1955, a lot happened in Kantian scholarship since then. But why do you wish to enlist Kant to your point of view so much? You can believe it whatever he thought. Undecidability is a much later concept, extracting it from CPR takes a great deal of modernizing creativity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104561/discussion-between-peterj-and-conifold).

Comment: If the answers below is enough for you, please accept it and we can "close" the post.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - There is only the one answer but this seems to be all there will be so feel free to close the post and put it out of its misery.

Comment: I've voted to close it. Nothing wrong with it but it's going nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

I conjecture two possibilities.

## Incapable of rational resolution due to equality of evidence or argument for and against

As regards antinomies I would hazard 'incapable of rational resolution'. In an antinomy there are two contradictory hypotheses, theories or claims and each is confirmed by equally cogent evidence or argument. Moreover, the equal confirmation of each hypothesis, etc., is such that no conceivable extra evidence or new argument could tilt the balance in favour of one hypothesis or the other. That, I think, is the sense in which an antinomy is said or supposed to be 'undecidable'.

But it is not to say that there **are** any such antinomies in philosophy or science. (It's 'highpriori' to suppose that no new argument could resolve an antinomy.)

## Consistent with all possible evidence

Metaphysics is not confined to antinomies, of course. Other metaphysical issues are also said by some to be undecidable. Take a claim such as that 'The concrete universal determines its own particularisation', which is what the late 19th-century Oxford Idealists such as Bernard Bosanquet said (M.B.Foster, 'The Concrete Universal: Cook Wilson and Bosanquet', Mind, Vol. 40, No. 157 (Jan., 1931), pp. 1-22: 1). This certainly looks like a metaphysical claim; and it sits within the complex metaphysical system of (Oxford) Absolute Idealism.

However, what evidence could one deploy to prove or defend it? Put another way and with acknowledgement to William James:  How would the world be different if it were **false**? Since we can't say or even begin to answer this question, we can designate it as 'undecidable'. That is, if we do not take the different path of saying that it is meaningless.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I especially like *"It's 'highpriori' to suppose that no new argument could resolve an antinomy."* Some things that were previously metaphysical speculation can now be answered with some degree of confidence (at least based on a straightforward realist reading of highly confirmed scientific theories). I can imagine folks centuries ago declaring questions about whether the universe had a beginning, whether determinism is true or not, where complex life came from, whether there are atomic building blocks, etc. as being undecidable in principle. Science has a way of surprising us!

Comment: Thanks for comment. I had in fact very much the scientific reshaping of our concepts in mind. Appreciated - Geoffrey

Comment: +1 also. It seems the word is generally given one of these two meanings in philosophy. They don;t exhaust the possibilities but I asked what folks usually mean by 'undecidable' and this seems to be it.

Comment: @AdamSharpe - I intended not to do any arguing back here but... If you think science can answer any of the questions you mention then I'd suggest you've misunderstood science. These questions have always belonged in metaphysics and always will. Science certainly surprises us at times but not by answering metaphysical questions. The methodology is not suitable. No question that was 'previously metaphysical' has been anwered by science. We needn't argue about this since there are no examples of such questions being answered by science.

Comment: Adam - What I meant was that some antinomies, e.g. of space and time, disappear when (courtesy of science) our concepts of space and time change.

Comment: @PeterJ I do not believe that I've misunderstood but I have made an assumption of scientific realism (which I do believe in, along with metaphysical realism). Let me ask a question. How do you, *a priori*, make a distinction between metaphysical and scientific questions and their methods? For me, the answer is not a priori, it involves (among other things) available evidence at the time (and so the boundary between science and metaphysics changes with time). The method of both fields is to apply a broad type of reasoning (that includes deduction, induction, abduction, statistics, etc).

Comment: @PeterJ But probably, there isn't a hard and fixed way to draw a distinction between questions and methods of both fields. That's my view. You seem to believe there is some absolute difference between the two such that science will never be able to tackle metaphysical questions. I don't want to put words in your mouth though, so I'd like to hear how you draw the distinction between metaphysics and science.

Comment: Geoffrey Thomas: Was your last comment intended for PeterJ?

Comment: Yes - sorry about the confusion. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: Science has progressed by making choices about metaphysical questions, but it has not answered them. One may point to the pragmatic success of the sciences in technology, et. al. as evidence that those choices reflect the underlying truth. But choices can lead to pragmatic success despite being embedded within a larger worldview that is itself faulty.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis One can be an instrumentalist or antirealist, but if one thinks such questions are answerable, *why can't* science provide answers? Modern cosmology supports that the universe is finite, quantum mechanics supports indeterminism, relativity supports a B-theory of time, etc. I don't know how empirical support for these positions can be less convincing than armchair arguments. I say this as someone who has deep respect for metaphysics. I hold many "controversial" metaphysical positions myself. It's just that empirical support would be *even nicer* than armchair arguments.

Comment: Here's another example for both transitionsynthesis and PeterJ, that will hopefully clarify my position. I'm a theist. (Nevermind whether it's true or not.) I like cosmological, teleological arguments, etc. I personally find them compelling. But theism would be *even more* compelling if I died and found myself in some kind of afterlife "face to face" with God. Empirical support seems to me to be more compelling than mere argument. Presumably we think the question of God's existence is a metaphysical question now, but it would cease to if we died and found ourselves in God's presence.

Comment: @AdamSharpe - I'm usually happy with the dictionary defitinion of metaphysics. Physics deals with relative knowledge and has nothing to say about absolutes. Metaphysical  questions are those that cannot be answered by the evidence of our physical senses. Dictionaries usually give a list. As an earlier comment notes, simply making choices about metaphysical theories does not make metaphysics go away. I'm slightly baffled as to why anyone would think physics can answer metaphysical questions. Sometime I wish this was a discussion forum. . .

Comment: @PeterJ Consider me equally baffled but in the opposite direction :)

Comment: @PeterJ Questions that are usually (or have been in the past) considered metaphysical include whether the universe is finite into the past, whether space and time are absolute, whether determinism is true, whether we have free will. Do you think, respectively, that big bang cosmology, relativity, quantum mechanics, or the Libet experiments have nothing interesting to add or do not support particular answers to any of these questions, or should be ignored? At the very least, philosophers who continue to endorse determinism (for example) usually feel the need to at least address the physics.

Comment: @AdamSharpe - I didn't mean to suggest physics is irrelevant to metaphysics. The point is just that metaphysical questions are 'meta -physical' and thus not answerable by physics. This has always been true and always will be. There are no examples of physics answering a metaphysical question.and there can never be one. You're right, of course, to say QM, relativity etc are important in metaphysics, (more important than is often acknowledged imho) but they are different areas of study relying on different methods. The metaphysical problems you list will never be resolved in physics.  . . .

Comment: @PeterJ By "answering a metaphysical question" do you mean providing an absolutely certain answer beyond all reasonable doubt? And is the method of metaphysics you mention that of pure a priori reasoning?

Comment: @AdamSharpe - I'm sorry but we cannot go into all this here. Shame, but it's the nature of the site. Maybe you could pursue it as a new question.